# Show related Content type content in block filtered by category

Tags: views

I have a Content Type called "All Documents", this uses a Category called "All Categories". Within "All Categories" I have multiple sub-categories eg "Sales", "Parts" and "Service".

I have a block that displays the related content of "All Documents" but this shows everything in that Category. How do I filter so if I am viewing "Parts" it will only show content related to that sub-category?

Answer (score 1):

At first, category and sub-category should be in Drupal-terms. Taxonomy vocabulary, taxonomy terms etc.

Assuming your related content block is created with contextual filters.

You can add these contextual filters to your views:

- **Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)**

*Display content if it has the selected taxonomy terms, or children of the selected terms. Due to additional complexity, this has fewer options than the versions without depth.*

- **Content: Has taxonomy term ID depth modifier**

*Allows the "depth" for Taxonomy: Term ID (with depth) to be modified via an additional contextual filter value.*